# Creating a server and sending a file from a client to another client through that server

Tags: java, file, client, server, send

I want to create an app in Java which uses a Server to send a file from a PC to another. I don't know how to make the server nor how to send the file. I would show some code but I haven't started yet with the app. If I know how to make the client app and create a file on the PC how do I connect the client with the server and send that file to another PC through that server.

Thanks and sorry for my bad explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Use Socket or RMI(based on Socket).
RMI is much easier.